# How can I graph a scatter plot in python using CanvasXpress Library?

Tags: canvas, graph, visualization

I can graph it using matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array([5,7,8,7,2,17,2,9,4,11,12,9,6])
y = np.array([99,86,87,88,111,86,103,87,94,78,77,85,86])

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

credit: https://www.w3schools.com/python/matplotlib_scatter.asp

How can I adjust my code to work with the CanvasXpress Library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Python, you can use the CanvasXpress for Python package, which is available on [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/canvasxpress/).  I'm the package author, and I collaborate with the Javascript library author.

To use the package with full functionality install it via pip:

`pip install canvasxpress[all]`

Assuming that we use the same arrays (but normal, not numpy), then an equivalent plot in Python and Jupyter Notebook/Labs is:

```
from canvasxpress.canvas import CanvasXpress
from canvasxpress.render.jupyter import CXNoteBook

x = [5, 7, 8, 7, 2, 17, 2, 9, 4, 11, 12, 9, 6]
y = [99, 86, 87, 88, 111, 86, 103, 87, 94, 78, 77, 85, 86]

scatter_plot = CanvasXpress(
    render_to="scatter_plot_example",
    data={
        "y": {
            "data": [[x[i], y[i]] for i in range(len(x))]
        }
    },
    config={
        "colorScheme": "Basic",
        "graphType": "Scatter2D",
        "yAxisTitle": " ",
        "yAxisTicksMajorShow": False,
        "yAxisTicksMinorShow": False,
        "xAxisTitle": " ",
        "xAxisTicksMajorShow": False,
        "xAxisTicksMinorShow": False,
    },
    width=600,
    height=400
)

display = CXNoteBook(scatter_plot)
display.render()
```

CanvasXpress.org maintains documentation and examples, such as for [ScatterPlot2D](https://canvasxpress.org/examples/scatter2d-1.html).  You can get Jupyter code for the displayed charts by right-clicking on the chart, then selecting *File*, then selecting *Reproducible Research*, and then finally choose *Show Jupyter Code*.

There are many configuration and data options.  Feel welcome to experiment, or to reach out at the [GitHub project page](https://github.com/docinfosci/canvasxpress-python/).  We're in the process of redoing our documentation, and many [Python examples or tutorials](https://github.com/docinfosci/canvasxpress-python/tree/main/tutorials) are available.

Comment: You will also find the information at https://canvasxpress.org/docs.html to be very helpful.  CanvasXpress offers a lot of functionality, and to make the most of it an understanding of how data is shaped is key.

Answer (score 0):

```
from canvasxpress.canvas import CanvasXpress
from canvasxpress.render.jupyter import CXNoteBook
import numpy as np

x = np.array([5,7,8,7,2,17,2,9,4,11,12,9,6])
y = np.array([99,86,87,88,111,86,103,87,94,78,77,85,86])
matrix = np.array([x, y]).T

cx = CanvasXpress(
    render_to = "example",
    data = {
        "smps": ["x", "y"],
        "data": matrix.tolist()
    },
    config = {
        "graphType": "Scatter2D"
    }
)

display = CXNoteBook(cx)
display.render()
```

The first three lines are import statements. The next three lines are the preparation of the data. CanvasXpress uses a data matrix in which each column goes to each axis. the next block of the code is the way CanvasXpress uses the data. For more info please visit [pypi.org/project/canvasxpress](https://pypi.org/project/canvasxpress).